# ReactJS. Firebase. TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

Below is a function that is called when a name is submitted. It goes to the firebase db and we then can see who is connected by looking at the db.

However, when I pull this data into an array of objects (users), I get stuck. I'm trying to push this data into this.state.names (array declared in the constructor state) but I just can't get my head round it.

The error message points to the function at the bottom of the code. Should the function be moved? Why is it not working? I've read many posts on 'this' but am struggling.

```
setName = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let name = this.state.name;
    let connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');

    connectedRef.on('value', (snapshot) =>{
      if (snapshot.val() === true) {
        // Connected
        const con = listRef.child(name);
        con.onDisconnect().remove();
        con.set(true);   //Write data (true) 
      }

      listRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        let users = [];
        snapshot.forEach( (user) => {
          users.push({
            id: snapshot.key,
            name: snapshot.val()
          })
        });
        setList(users);
      });
      function setList(users) {
        this.setState({
          names: users
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your callbacks are using the `function` syntax, which causes `this` to be out of scope. Modify your `.on` callbacks to be arrow functions

Comment: Could you explain further, please?

Comment: Just tried that for both the snapshot and the foreach function, and separately. The problem persists. OP edited to include arrow functions, but this is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal functions have its own context. To be able to recieve correct `this` from the upper level, you need to modify your `setList` function to be arrow function. Like this:

```
const setList = (users) => {
  this.setState({
    names: users
  })
}
```

And also do not forget to lift it up, declaration should be before usage, since `const` variables doesn't hoist.